# Google app script External APIs permission issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script to call external api, here's my code...

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var formData = {
    'fname': 'test',
    'lname': 'test',
    'email': 'test',
    'phone': 'test',
    'timetocontact': 'test',
    'time': 'test'
  };

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData
  };
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.test.com/api/leads', options);
  sh.getRange(row, 5).setValue(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

when I save and run it manually it asks for permission and after allowing the browser still shows this...

[image]

I have tried many suggested solutions online, like updating manifest and add the following...

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://www.test.com/api/leads"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

but nothing seems to work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have seen this issue before because of multiple accounts logged in. Can you please try one thing. Open a new incognito tab and login to Google and then try and run it

Comment: i tried logging in incognito and created new sheet and again allowed the asked permissions, still the same issue

Comment: Use an installable trigger

Comment: This  message usually is displayed when the authorization scope isn't explicitly set. So, this is where the documentation adresses it: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app  .

Comment: hi all, installable triggers worked! Thank you